# Usar <style> dentro de if do javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, Eu estava fazer um teste em javascript para ver se o valor de dois inputs eram diferentes, caso fossem eu mudaria o background de um input para vermelho, e tentei abrindo as tags do style dentro do if e em vez de aparecer assim

[image]

aparece assim

[image]

codigo Javascript

```
function verificarIgual()
    {
        var senha = document.getElementById('senha_cadastro');
        var confirmar = document.getElementById('confirmarsenha_cadastro');

        if(senha.value != confirma.value)
        {
            <style>
            </style>
        }

    }
```

Esse input que quero deixar vermelho

```
          <tr>
            <td id="design_geral_escrita" height="22" align="left">
            <label for="senha_cadastro"></label>
            <input width="200" type="text" name="senha_cadastro" id="senha_cadastro" /></td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Só para te adiantar, ta bem no caminho errado. Hehe. Vou tentar lhe ajudar. Qual `input` você quer deixar com background vermelho?

Comment: Coloquei o input na pergunta

Comment: Isso que você tem dentro do if é um erro de sintaxe em JavaScript, e ele interrompe a execução do código.  Não pode misturar HTML e JS desse jeito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me arrisco em uma solução, que consiste no seguinte:

**Explicação**

A tag [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) é utilizada unica e exclusivamente para a declaração de estilos (CSS) para o HTML. E com certeza não deve ser inserido dinamicamente na pagina para alterar um estilo qualquer como você está tentado (apesar de ser possível).

Tendo esse conhecimento, vamos para o modo correto. Que seria utilizar o próprio javascript para manipular o [DOM HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM). Onde você pode manipular o [`style` de um elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) e consequentemente suas propriedades, sendo no seu caso a propriedade `backgroundColor`, obtendo um resultado equivalente ao declarado na tag `<style>`.

**A implementação**

O que você pode fazer então é o seguinte:

```
if(senha.value != confirmar.value){
    senha.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    confirmar.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";           
}else{
    senha.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    confirmar.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

Sendo um exemplo completo assim:

```js
function verificarIgual() {
  if (senha.value != confirmar.value) {
    senha.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    confirmar.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
  } else {
    senha.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    confirmar.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
  }
}

var senha = document.getElementById('senha_cadastro');
var confirmar = document.getElementById('confirmarsenha_cadastro');
senha.onkeyup = verificarIgual;
confirmar.onkeyup = verificarIgual;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="senha_cadastro" />
<input type="text" id="confirmarsenha_cadastro" />
```

[Também há uma versão do exemplo online no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/8c2me7qr/1/)

Fontes: [Using dynamic styling information (Em Inglês)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information).

Comment: tem um jeito de mudar a cor para vermelho sem ter que apertar o botão ?? logo que os dois estejam diferentes já muda

Comment: Sim, @LucasCarezia, mas dai seria com o evento `onkeyup`, vou atualizar o meu exemplo.

Comment: @LucasCarezia, atualizei minha resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode declarar uma folha de estilos css dentro de um javascript. Substitua o código `<style></style>` por `senha.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";`, por exemplo.

Veja o exemplo abaixo para melhor entendimento, nele usei um botão apenas pra chamar a função que simula um evento de erro, a linha que te interessa mesmo é a que falei acima.

```js
function error() {
  var senha = document.getElementById('senha');
  senha.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
}
```

```html
<p>Simulação erro</p>
<input type="password" id="senha" />

<button type="button" onclick="error()">Simular erro</button>
```